# Variable within an array PHP

Tags: php

I want the variable to be parsed within the array so when I echo $head['meta_title'] , lol is displayed. I have tried wrapping it in double quotes but that doesn't seem to work either, is there any way round this?? Thanks!

I am getting either unexpected T_VARIABLE and when I use double quotes I get unexpected ""

```
$meta_title = "lol";

public $head = array
(
    "title"        => "blah",
    "meta_title"   => $meta_title,
    "meta_content" => $meta_content
);
```

Comment: Why have you put a comma after $meta_content? Remove it

Comment: remove the comma at the end of `$meta_content,`

Comment: @MuthuKumaran The last comma isn't doing any harm.

Comment: PHP.net includes the comma in their array examples, so I assumed it was good practice

Comment: The comma, although it isn't harmful, does encourage a bad habit of using them everywhere. In a SQL select list, for example, it would be a syntax error.  Worse, it is fine in JavaScript arrays for _most browsers_ but will fail in IE<=8 causing ambiguous errors and hard to track down bugs.  Best not to get in the habit of using trailing commas.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah, you're absolutely right. I should have put it into those words. I actually wanted to say, that the comma isn't causing the error. And you're so right, trailing commas in JavaScript are a horror to find and fix …

Comment: @insertusernamehere Oh - I wasn't addressing that at you, but at the OP's assumption that the PHP docs encourage any kind of good practice :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Still good to point it out. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use an expression to initialize a class property.  The values of the two variables are not known until runtime, and therefore can't be used in the declaration. Instead, define them in the constructor.

```
public $head = array
(
    // The title as a string literal is ok...
    "title"        => "blah",
    "meta_title"   => NULL,
    "meta_content" => NULL
);
// Pass them to the constructor as parameters
public function __construct($meta_title, $meta_content)
{ 
  // Initialize them in the constructor. 
  $this->head['meta_title'] = $meta_title;
  $this->head['meta_content'] = $meta_content;
}
```

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**

Comment: Ah ok, that would make sense, I actually have them defined in another class,

  `class standardHandle 
  {

   //-- <head> Variables --//
   
   //Metadata
   public $meta_title = "lol";
   public $meta_content = "mao";
   
   //Stylesheet
   public $style = array (
    "link" => "style.css",
    "type" => "screen",
   );
   
   

  }`

Comment: Ok, do I add them to the contructor of their native class?

Comment: @user1650757 Pass them into the constructor of the class that needs to use them.  If they were defined in another class, that would be something like: `new ThisClass($otherclass->meta_title, $otherclass->meta_content);`

Comment: hm is there any other alternative, what if I had hundreds of variables from the other class that needed passing...apologies if im not making sense, quite sleep deprived right now

edit: if i was to wrap them in their native class constructor..would that work?

Comment: @user1650757 you can pass them as an array into the constructor and unpack them inside.  However, if you have many variables that need to be passed between classes, it possibly suggests a design problem, where one class ought to be inheriting from the other, or instantiated inside the other, for example...

Comment: hmm okay, ill look into my design, I'm a bit of a php noob and just starting to delve into oop, but thats really good to know thanks, also i will omit the comma from now on

Comment: What exactly is the difference between inheriting and being instantiated inside the other? does inheriting involve extend?

Comment: Inheriting means extending - wherein all the public and protected properties would be inherited by the extending class, and if they are declared in the parent class, would therefore be declared the same way in the child class unless you change them.  Instantiating inside isn't the same thing at all really - it would potentially make the child class a property of the parent class, but still require some work to push variables into its constructor - they wouldn't be inherited.

Answer (score 2):

If this is within an object you cannot assign a variable this way. You have to set it using the `__construct`-method.

Answer (score 0):

The public needs to be removed before $head. I've created an example in PHP Sandbox.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d17bc90e1291f6a3b23537984df755e40446add6

Comment: I would say the `public` shows more, that he is trying to do this within the scope of an object even if the OP didn't post the whole thing.

Comment: This is a `public` class property declaration.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php